# Twisted - succes (or failure) callback for LineReceiver sendLine

Tags: twisted, twisted.internet

I'm still trying to master Twisted while in the midst of finishing an application that uses it.

My question is:

My application uses LineReceiver.sendLine to send messages from a Twisted TCP server.
I would like to know if the sendLine succeeded.

I gather that I need to somehow add a success (and error?) callback to sendLine but I don't know how to do this.

Thanks for any pointers / examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define "succeeded" in order to come up with an answer to this.

All `sendLine` does *immediately* (probably) is add some bytes to a send buffer.  In some sense, as long as it doesn't raise an exception (eg, `MemoryError` because your line is too long or `TypeError` because your line was the number `3` instead of an actual line) it has succeeded.

That's not a very useful kind of success, though.  Unfortunately, the useful kind of success is more like "the bytes were added to the send buffer, the send buffer was flushed to the socket, the peer received the bytes, and the receiving application acted on the data in a persistent way".

Nothing in `LineReceiver` can tell you that all those things happened.  The standard solution is to add some kind of *acknowledgement* to your protocol: when the receiving application has acted on the data, it sends back some bytes that tell the original sender the message has been handled.

You won't get `LineReceiver.sendLine` to help you much here because all it really knows how to do is send some bytes in a particular format.  You need a more complex protocol to handle acknowledgements.

Fortunately, Twisted comes with a few.  `twisted.protocols.amp` is one: it offers remote method calls (complete with responses) as a basic feature.  I find that AMP is suitable for a wide range of applications so it's often safe to recommend for new development.  It largely supersedes the older `twisted.spread` (aka "PB") which also provides both remote method calls and remote object references (and is therefore more complex - in my experience, more complex than most applications need).  There are also some options that are a bit more standard: for example, Twisted Web includes an HTTP implementation (HTTP, as you may know, is good at request/response style interaction).

Comment: Thanks Jean-Paul. I'd settle for "the send buffer was flushed to the socket" if I could get that.  The receiving server, unfortunately, runs code that I can't access or change.  It just sits there chomping up lines that I send it and processing them.

Comment: Unfortunately, while Twisted can sort of give you "the userspace buffer was flushed to the kernel" it can't give you "the kernel buffer was flushed to the network".  But look into `IProducer` and `IConsumer` for the former.  If you write a producer and register it with the transport (which is a consumer), the transport will call `pauseProducing` on your producer when the userspace buffer is "full" and `resumeProducing` when the userspace buffer is "empty".  This is sort of the information you want.  There are no public APIs for getting the information in a more direct way.

Comment: I think it's worth emphasizing that there are easily half a dozen errors that would prevent your `sendLine` data from getting to your peer, even after it's made it across the kernel/userspace boundary.  If you have an abnormal termination to your connection (your foreign host disconnects you, your router explodes, the world comes to an end), chances are good that several of the last "successfully" transmitted lines will still be lost.  It would be useful to know why it is that you want to know about success/failure; there might be other information that would be better for your use-case.

Comment: Glyph - I'll start another question regarding my use case.  You've raised an interesting point